# Delphi - OSX - Load font from memory stream

Tags: macos, delphi, fonts, core-text

I am trying to load a font from a memory stream on OSX in a Firemonkey (FMX) application with Delphi.

Here is the code I tried:

```
procedure LoadFontFromStream(SourceStream:TStream);
var cfData:CFDataRef;
    fontBuffer:TBytes;
    fontRef: CGFontRef;
    provider: CGDataProviderRef;
    currentStrRef: CFStringRef;
    currentStr: string;
    streamSize: Int64;
    ctFontReference : CTFontRef;
    ctAscent, ctDescent, ctCapHeight: CGFloat;
begin
  streamSize := SourceStream.Size;
  SetLength(fontBuffer, streamSize);
  SourceStream.Read(fontBuffer[0], streamSize);

  cfData := CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, @fontBuffer[0],
    streamSize, kCFAllocatorNull);
  provider := CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(cfData);
  CFRelease(cfData);

  fontRef := CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);
  CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

  if fontRef <> nil then
  begin
    ctFontReference := CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont(fontRef,0.0, nil, nil);
    if ctFontReference <> nil then
    begin
      ctCapHeight := CTFontGetCapHeight(ctFontReference);
      ctAscent := CTFontGetAscent(ctFontReference);
      ctDescent := CTFontGetDescent(ctFontReference);
    end;
    currentStrRef := CTFontCopyFamilyName(ctFontReference);
    currentStr := CFToDelphiString(currentStrRef);
    Log.d('Family name: %s',[currentStr]);
    CFRelease(currentStrRef);
    currentStrRef := CTFontCopyPostscriptName(ctFontReference);
    currentStr := CFToDelphiString(currentStrRef);
    Log.d('Postscript name: %s',[currentStr]);
    CFRelease(currentStrRef);
    currentStrRef := CTFontCopyDisplayName(ctFontReference);
    currentStr := CFToDelphiString(currentStrRef);
    Log.d('Display name: %s',[currentStr]);
    CFRelease(currentStrRef);
  end;
end;
```

The familyname, postscript name and display name all display correct on the debugger. However, the font is not loaded/displayed on my form. I tried enumerating all font families after running the code and it seems my font (Open Sans) is not present. Here is how I enumerate the font families:

```
procedure ListFonts();
var fontFamilyArray: CFArrayRef;
    i : CFIndex;
    NumFamilies: CFIndex;
    family: CFStringRef;
    familyStr: string;
    foundOpenSans: Boolean;
begin
  foundOpenSans := False;
  fontFamilyArray := CTFontManagerCopyAvailableFontFamilyNames();
  NumFamilies  :=  CFArrayGetCount(fontFamilyArray);
  for i := 0 to NumFamilies-1 do
  begin
    family := CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(fontFamilyArray, i);
    familyStr := CFToDelphiString(family);
    if familyStr.StartsWith('Open') then
    begin
      foundOpenSans := true;
      Log.d('Found %s', [familyStr]);
    end;
  end;

  if not foundOpenSans then
    Log.d('Open Sans not found');

  CFRelease(fontFamilyArray);
end;
```

I know that loading custom fonts is possible by setting ATSApplicationFontsPath in the info.plist file and placing the files in a folder with my bundle. I tried that and that works. However, I need to load the font from a memory stream.

Any ideas why that code doesn't load the font? I am running the code to load the font before creating any forms in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you registering that font with the font manager. Have a look at [CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_FontManager_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont).
The documentation explicitly mentions this function for registering fonts that were constructed from memory.

Comment: This function is only available on 10.8 and later and my code needs to  run also on 10.7. However, I am not sure this would be the solution. This is what I based my code on: https://github.com/julianstorer/JUCE/blob/master/modules/juce_graphics/native/juce_mac_Fonts.mm If you go and check that repository you will see it doesn't use CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont anywhere in the code. Any other ideas?

Comment: If I read that code correctly, then it loads the font into a ctFontRef. Then this ctFontRef is used inside that library for drawing, .... That way it doesn't need to be registered.
You're trying to find this font by name as if it had been registered. That is different.

Comment: That's a good catch. Indeed, it doesn't need to be registered that way. I finally found the error and added an answer for it. Not sure how to do it on 10.7 though. CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont only works on OSX 10.8 and later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the buffer I used. Here is how I solved it.

```
procedure LoadFontFromStream(SourceStream:TStream);
var cfData:CFDataRef;
    fontBuffer:TBytes;
    fontRef: CGFontRef;
    provider: CGDataProviderRef;
    streamSize: Int64;
    theError: CFErrorRef;
    errorDescription : CFStringRef;
    errorDescriptionString : string;
    registerFontValue: Integer;
begin
  streamSize := SourceStream.Size;
  SetLength(fontBuffer, streamSize);
  SourceStream.Read(fontBuffer[0], streamSize);
  cfData := CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, @fontBuffer[0],streamSize);
  provider := CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(cfData);
  CFRelease(cfData);
  fontRef := CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);
  CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
  if fontRef <> nil then
  begin
    theError := nil;
    registerFontValue :=CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(fontRef, @theError);
    if theError <> nil then
    begin
      errorDescription := CFErrorCopyDescription(theError);
      errorDescriptionString := CFToDelphiString(errorDescription);
      Log.d('Error loading font: %s', [errorDescriptionString]);
      CFRelease(errorDescription);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

However, this only works on OSX 10.8 and later as CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont is not availabile on OSX 10.7. Any idea on what method is available on OSX 10.7?